# How to include time as a variable in Python Gekko?

Tags: python, differential-equations, odeint, gekko

I need to include time in my model for the solution of a complex set of differential equations. Here is a simple problem that demonstrates the issue with constant `k=0.1` and initial condition `y(0)=10`.

[image: differential equation]

I tried it in Python Gekko but can't figure out how to include time as a variable. In Scipy ODEINT, the function has time and the state variables. In Gekko, I define `m.time` as the points where I would like to see the solution but using `m.time` in the equation has an error.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()    # create GEKKO model
m.time = np.linspace(0,20) # time points
k = 0.1        # constant
y = m.Var(10)  # create GEKKO variable
m.Equation(y.dt()==-k*m.time*y) # create GEKKO equation

# solve ODE
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()

# plot results
plt.plot(m.time,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

```
 @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 ((-0.12244897959183675)*(v1))((-0.163265306122449)*(v1))
 STOPPING...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ode_time.py", line 13, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2103, in solve
    raise Exception(response)
Exception:  @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 ((-0.12244897959183675)*(v1))((-0.163265306122449)*(v1))
 STOPPING...
```

How can I include time as a variable in Gekko equations?

Answer (score 1):

You can include time in a Gekko model by adding a new variable `t` and equation `d(t)/dt=1`.

```py
t = m.Var(0); m.Equation(t.dt()==1)
```

Here is a solution to the differential equation problem.

[image: Differential Equation Solution]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()    # create GEKKO model
m.time = np.linspace(0,20) # time points
k = 0.1        # constant
y = m.Var(10)  # create GEKKO variable
t = m.Var(0); m.Equation(t.dt()==1)
m.Equation(y.dt()==-k*t*y) # create GEKKO equation

# solve ODE
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()

# plot results
plt.plot(m.time,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

For another example, see [problem #3 for Python Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/PythonDifferentialEquations) or the same [problem #3 with ODEINT](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations).

Comment: Is there a mechanism to pass time generated like this to an existing function (say, the exponential function) that takes in a numeral value? I tried 't' but that gives an error, so I am using 't.value' but I don't know if that gives the current value of time or the initial value of time.

Comment: The `t.value` before the `m.solve()` function is the initial condition. After the solve, the `t.value` is the solution to the differential equation `t.dt()==1`. The `t` variable can be used in a function, but it is only in symbolic form until the `m.solve()` command. There are no call-backs from Gekko into those functions during the solution.